# set property of child control viewmodel, from the parent view xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to set a property of view model for a child control, from the parent view xaml.

So I want the parent xaml to be something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainUserControl"
...>
<Grid...>
    <local:ChildDetailView x:Name="childView1" ChildVMProperty="ValueOptions.Option1"/>
    <local:ChildDetailView x:Name="childView2" ChildVMProperty="ValueOptions.Option2"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Where ChildVMProperty is a property on the ChildDetailViewModel (incase it is relevant, the property takes an enum of type ValueOptions).

Note that the ViewModels are being set in the code behind (not in the xaml) as actually I am using DI in the ViewModels to inject a prism event aggregator.

When I try to do something like this, the xaml complains because it obviously knows nothing about the ChildViewModel class. What is the correct syntax to to do this, or if it is not as straight forward, what options do I have to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first create your `ChildDetailView.xaml` file. Let's say you put this file in the namespace `MyApp.Controls`, then your XAML above would be something like

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainUserControl"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls" >
    <Grid ...>
        <local:ChildDetailView x:Name="childView1" ChildVMProperty="ValueOptions.Option1"/>
        <local:ChildDetailView x:Name="childView2" ChildVMProperty="ValueOptions.Option2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You will have to ensure that you have `DependencyProperty` (DP) `ChildVMProperty` defined on your `UserControl` also - but this is another question and there are plenty of answers on that particular subject. To add a DP for the view you may need to sub-class the particular control you are attempting to target.

Another alternative to using DPs for the properties is using converters.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. If I add a DP to the child View, how does the child ViewModel know what the value is? (it is the child ViewModel that needs to work with the value)

Comment: Through a Binding to the DP. `ChildVMProperty={Binding PropertyInTheViewModel}`.

Comment: If I bind the property, then I'm not able to actually set the value in the xaml. I had looked into OneWayToSource binding, but could not work out how to specify the value (TargetNullValue doesn't work).